Composer v2.6.6 - job completing successfully, Task exited with Negsignal.SIGKIL
we have Composer 2.6.6(Airflow 2.5.3), and a job VANI-UEBA3 which is running on Dataproc Serverless Batches ... the job runs through fine (as shown on the Dataproc Serverless UI),
but the composer UI is showing errors very often - error: Task exited with Negsignal.SIGKIL - which indicates the process is killed due to more resources being used by the task
snippet of the error :
[2024-06-10, 00:41:54 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:353} INFO - Getting connection using google.auth.default() since no explicit credentials are provided.
[2024-06-10, 00:44:32 UTC] {local_task_job.py:212} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
[2024-06-10, 00:44:33 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2599} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

However, when i go to the Dataproc serverless UI, the job has actually succeeded.
Also, the job is running on the Dataproc serverless cluster .. not on the airflow cluster so ideally there should not be an Negsignal.SIGKIL error after the job is completed. (if the job is not launched, that might be acceptable error IMO)
Any ideas on what might be causing this issue and how to fix this ?
tia!

I'd check how many parallel jobs would be running on the same worker, while this job is running, as in the error timestamp assuming the job started at [1.1] and hit neg.signal at [1.2] in those three min did it display anything about the dataproc cluster.? i.e starting dataproc cluster etc
As it's pointed out that dataproc cluster will be doing all the processing, I'd check if there are any other jobs eating up memory causing the worker to go OOM. and what is the worker concurrency value.? if it's too high meaning worker will take up more task and resource starvation can occur. maybe check if the issue is transient or happens all the time.
[1] snippet of the error :
[1.1] [2024-06-10, 00:41:54 UTC] {credentials_provider.py:353} INFO - Getting connection using google.auth.default() since no explicit credentials are provided.
[1.2] [2024-06-10, 00:44:32 UTC] {local_task_job.py:212} INFO - Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGKILL
